# Issue executing ansible play due to undefined variable in include_vars file

Tags: variables, ansible, undefined, file-extension, ansible-inventory

Below is my playbook:

```
  tasks:
   - name: Construct File Path on Destination Server.
     include_vars:
       file: "{{ item }}"
     with_fileglob:
        - "vars/myvars.yaml"

   - name: setting_facts for BackEnd
     set_fact:
       fpath_BackEnd_APP: []
     set_fact:
       fpath_BackEnd_APP: "{{ fpath_BackEnd_APP + [ BASEPATH ~ '/' ~ vars[ (item | splitext)[1].split('.')[1] ] ~ '/' ~ item | basename ] }}"
     with_items:
       - "{{ Source_Filenames.split(',') }}"
```

Here is my variable file:

cat vars/myvars.yaml

```
com: /path/to/com/folder
src: /path/to/src/folder
```

The below playbook run works fine as expected.

```
ansible-playbook  /app/deploy.yml -e Source_Filenames=/app/testing_purpose.src,/app/testing_purpose.com
```

However, when I pass filename which do not have a dot(.) i.e no file extension the ansible play is not able to find the the variable in  myvars.yaml and errors as below:

```
ansible-playbook  /app/deploy.yml -e Source_Filenames=/app/testing_purpose.src,/app/testing_purpose,/app/testing_purpose.com,/app/testing_moht

"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 1\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/deploy.yml'"
```

My requirement is to allocate "/path/to/no-ext/folder" for variable "fpath_BackEnd_APP" incase a file without extension is passed. Files with extensions .com & .src work fine as they get the variable value substituted from the myvars.yml file. For any other file extensions like .jpg 
 or .txt the playbook should fall with the variable undefined error.
Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Those last examples aren't  valid `ansible-playbook` command lines.   They would fail with a message like `ERROR! the playbook: Source_Filenames=/app/testing_purpose.src,/app/testing_purpose.com could not be found`

Comment: I m sorry added the -e option for passing parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take as an entry `/toto/pipo`

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (item | splitext) }}" -e item=/toto/pipo
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "('/toto/pipo', '')"
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (item | splitext)[1] }}" -e item=/toto/pipo
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": ""
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (item | splitext)[1].split('.') }}" -e item=/toto/pipo
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        ""
    ]
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (item | splitext)[1].split('.')[1] }}" -e item=/toto/pipo
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 1"
}
```

Whereas, if you pass an entry containing an extension like `/toto/pipo.test`:

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (item | splitext)[1].split('.')[1] }}" -e item=/toto/pipo.test
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "test"
}
```

Meanwhile, you can set a default value when the expression itself does not return a value:

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ (item | splitext)[1].split('.')[1] | default('') }}" -e item=/toto/pipo
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Comment: I want the error to appear if the user passes -e  Source_Filenames=/app/testing_purpose.jpg,/app/testing_purpose.com as .jpg is an invalid unwanted file extention. I want the playbook to pass only those  variables matching file extensions in myvars.yml file or files without extensions. This the default may not be the solution here. Please suggest.

Comment: Since what you just stated in your comment is not part of your question, I suggest you edit it to clearly state what kind of problem you are trying to solve because I clearly did not get what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Updated the original post with a clearer requirement

Comment: your solution helped save the day !! Thank you